# D3.js treemap cells overlap with each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, treemap

When I draw my treemap in the local server, the treemap cells overlap with each other. Ive tried using other tiling algorithms but that did not work. I have also tried messing round with my linear scales but I can seem to get the correct scaling. Would this be a scaling problem or something else. I have also messed with the transform attributes but that just made it even worse. The current one I have is the best one that I find works.

```
createTreemap() {
        //***VARS */
        var margin = { left: 100, right: 10, top: 10, bottom:100}

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
          //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + margin.left + "," +  margin.top+ ")"; });
        var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right //width = 960
        var height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom //height = 570

        // var width = +svg.attr("width")
        // var height = +svg.attr("height")

        //linear scales
          var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,height])
            .range([0,height/2])

          var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,width])
            .range([0,width/2])

          var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0,width])
            .range([0,width/2])

        //creating a treemap variable
          var treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
          .tile(d3.treemapBinary) //type of squares
          .size([width/2,height/2]) //size
          .round(true) //if number are decimal, round to int. when true
          .paddingInner(1) //padding between rectangles (1px)



        //****loading data into function****
        d3.json("../static/warehouses.json").then(function(data){
          var root = d3.hierarchy(data, d => d.warehouses) 
            .sum(function(d){return d.itemCount}) //formating data to a more complex hierarchy form
          
          treemapLayout(root)//passing data stuct to treemap variable
          console.log(treemapLayout(root))//logging to console


          
          //setting canvas sizes
          var cells = svg.selectAll("g")
              .data(root.leaves())
              .enter()
              .append("g")
                //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + scale(d.x0) + "," +  scale(d.y0)+ ")"; });


          cells.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0 })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1  })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y1 })
            .attr("fill", "#ccc")
              

          cells.append("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 + 5 })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0 + 15 })
              .style("font", "15px monospace")
              .text(function(d){ return d.data.name})
              .attr("fill", "black")
          cells.append("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 +5 })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0 +27 })
              .style("font", "10px monospace")
              .text(function(d) { return "Item count: " + d.data.itemCount })
              .attr("fill", "black")
        })
      },
```

To be specific the warehouse "PROVEEDOR" is overlaying or laid over the warehouse "Wec"
[image of treemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM9uW.png) what would be the cause of this? Because I thought d3 automatically figures out where each x0, y0, x1, y1 should go so they dont overlap?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Just learning d3 but ran into the same problem that brought me to this post. I solved it by debugging this code:

```
 cells.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0 })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1  })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y1 })
            .attr("fill", "#ccc")
```

with this code...

```
cell.append("rect")
          .attr("width", d=> d.x1 - d.x0)
          .attr("height", d => d.y1 - d.y0)
```